# Formatting data set through laravel collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-collection, laravel-6.2

I'm having two models `Roles` and `Specialisation`, both of them are related as `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relationship with each other. I've another model named `Company` which is in `Many-to-many` relationship with each one of them. I'm working on a graph where I'm required to have a data set as below:

```
data: {
      Consultant: { "Avenger": 14, "Challenger": 647 },
      Contractor: { "124 Spider": 4478, "500": 12685, "500L": 1664, "500X": 7665 },
      Manufacturer: { "C-Max": 390, "Edge": 1423, "Escape": 308296, "E-Series": 53304, "Expedition": 5183, "Explorer": 2731, "Fiesta": 46249},
      Miscellaneous: { "C-Max": 18390, "Edge": 142603, "Escape": 308296, "E-Series": 53304, "Expedition": 883, "Explorer": 2731 },
      Owner: { "C-Max": 18390 },
      Supplier: { "Expedition": 5883, "Explorer": 271131, "Fiesta": 46249, "Flex": 2289, "Focus": 1583 },
  }
```

Here `Consultant`, `Contractor`, `Manufacturer`, ... etc represents the `role->name`, inside the index of object I've `specialisation->name` and the number which represents the companies count associated with them, I want to achieve with the below codes:

```
$data = Role::whereNull('parent_id')->get();

$roles = collect($data)->map(function ($role) {
    $specialisation = Specialisation::where('parent_id', $role->id)->get();

    $element[$role->name] = array(
        //specialisation and companies_count
    );

    return $element;
});
```

I'm bit confused on achieving this. Help me out in this. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you're using Eloquent, you can try reading Eloquent Relationships in the Laravel offical documentation

Comment: @Joseph I know about relationship, its about formatting or mapping the query data.

Comment: To clarify, what you want to do is:
Get all Role ($data) -> get all Specialization associated with each Role -> get all companies_count of each Specialization

How about 
`$element[$role->name] = array(
        //specialisation and companies_count
        $specialisation->name => $specialisation->companies_count
);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find any solutions from `collection` methods. To achieve this I tried creating an object with help of `stdClass()` and then inside object I created another object and then returned the whole data. Something like this:

```
$data = Role::whereNull('parent_id')->withCount('companies')->get();

$object = new \stdClass();

foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    $name = $value->name;

    $specialisation = Specialisation::where('parent_id', $value->id)->withCount('companies')->get();

    $ob = new \stdClass();

    foreach ($specialisation as $sp => $spec)
    {
        $n = $spec->name;
        $ob->$n = $spec->companies_count;
    }
    $object->$name = $ob;
}

return response()->json(['data' => $object], 200);
```

Hope this help someone. Thanks.